# Java - How to join multiple values in a multidimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm beginner programmer, I have fallen into a rabbit hole trying to understand how to use arrays. I'm trying to create a table using multidimensional arrays and I am looking to create a table with 7 rows and 5 columns.

- column 1 = will take values from the user input.This input is stored in an array.
- column 2 = will print the highest input in that array.
- column 3 = will print the lowest input in that array
- column 4 = will print take the increment Total. i.e current input + previous input.
- column 5 = will take the increment average. i.e Total/Index

### Complete Code below

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Numbers {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     //----User Input - Add values to array ----//

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

    int places = 7; 
    int [] values = new int [places];
    int sum = 0; 

    System.out.println("Enter a Numbers:");

        for (int count = 0; count < places; count++)
            {       
            values[count] = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println(values[count]);
            }

     //----------------Total---------------------//

        for (int numb : values)
            {
            sum = sum + numb;
            }

        System.out.println("\n Total:" +  sum);

   //----------Average------------------------/

        double avg = 0; 
        if (values.length > 0)
            {
            avg = sum / values.length;
            }

        System.out.printf("\n Average:"+ avg);


   //---------Table Start---------------------//


        int [] [] table = new int [7][5];

        for (int row =0; row < 7; row++)
            for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
            table [row][column] = getTable(column, column, column, column, avg);


        System.out.println("\n\nIndex\tInput\tHigest\tLowest\tTotal\tAverage"); 

        for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++)
            {
            System.out.print((row + 1) +  " "); 
            for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
                System.out.print("\t  " + table[row][column] + " "); 
            System.out.println(); 
            }

        }

public static int getTable(int input, int highest, int lowest, int total, double average) {

/* TO DO: 
     * - add each user input from values array into Input column
     * 
     * - add highest/lowest values in the Highest/Lowest column
     * 
     * - add each of the array element total in Total column - this column should take previous Total plus current total. 
     *          i.e Total = Total + Input
     * 
     * - add Average - Current average value. 
     */

    return 0;

    }
}
```

What I don't know is how to get my code to fill each of the rows using different values each time.

**For Example:**

Index 1

- 1st column take first value of the values array
- 2nd column: take highest value of the values array
- 3rd column: take lowest value of the values array
- 4th column: take previous element of values array plus the current value
- 5th column: take total/index

I know that may need to create a method to get my program to loop through but I just don't know how to do it. I've tried a few different ways, but I'm just getting confused. In the left corner of the screenshot below, is how the columns would look like. Notice how they are all returning 0, which I known that is coming from the getTable method that I created, which is doing just that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, in this code, you're looping over all the columns:

```
    for (int row =0; row < 7; row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
        table [row][column] = getTable(column, column, column, column, avg);
```

You don't want to do this.  Looping over all the columns would make sense if you were doing pretty much the same thing with each column.  But you're not.  You want each column to have the result of a very different computation.  So it would make more sense to say something like

```
    for (int row = 0; row < table.length; row++) {
        table[row][0] = getFirstValue(values);
        table[row][1] = getHighestValue(values);
        table[row][2] = getLowestValue(values);
        ...
```

and so on.  (However, I don't really understand how "values" is supposed to be used.  You're inputting one set of values, but you're creating a table with 7 rows based on that one set of values.  Perhaps there's more things wrong with your code.)

Note a couple of things: (1) I replaced `7` with `table.length` in the loop.  `table.length` is the number of rows, and will be 7.  But if you change things to use a different number of rows, then using `table.length` means you don't have to change the `for` loop.  (2) My code passes `values` as a parameter to the different methods, which is necessary because the methods will be making computations on the input values.  Your code didn't pass `values` to `getTable()`, so there's no way `getTable()` could have performed any computations, since it didn't have the data.

The code could be improved further.  One way would be to define constants in the class like

```
private static final int FIRST_VALUE_COLUMN = 0;
private static final int HIGHEST_VALUE_COLUMN = 1;

...

        table[row][FIRST_VALUE_COLUMN] = getFirstValue(values);
        table[row][HIGHEST_VALUE_COLUMN] = getHighestValue(values);
```

which would be more readable.

A more significant improvement would be not to use a 2-D array at all.  Since you have five values with different meanings, the normal approach in Java would be to create a class with five instance variables to hold the computed data:

```
public class ComputedData {
    private int firstValue;
    private int highestValue;
    private int lowestValue;

    public void setFirstValue(int firstValue) {
        this.firstValue = firstValue;
    }

    public int getFirstValue() {
         return firstValue;
    }

    // similarly for other fields
}
```

`table` would then be a 1-dimensional array of `ComputedData`.

This is better because now you don't have to assign meaningless column numbers to different computed values.  Instead, the names tell you just what each computed value is.  Also, it means you can add new values later that don't have to be `int`.  With an array, all elements in the array have to be the same type (you can use `Object` which can then hold a value of any type, but that can make the code messier).  In fact, you may decide later that the "average" should be a `double` instead of an `int` since averages of integers aren't always integers.  You can make this change pretty easily by changing the type of an instance variable in the `ComputedData` class.  If you use an array, though, this kind of change gets pretty complicated.